# Correct color display in blending mode-blend-mode

Tags: css, sass

The situation is as follows: there is a floating block with `position: fixed` (navigation menu). `mix-blend-mode: difference` is applied to it, this block, when scrolling, runs over a block with `background: black` and everything works as it should (black text on a white background and white text on a black background). However, when hovering over the mouse (`:hover` effect), the color should be `#dc145c`, but because of `mix-blend-mode: difference` it is green. `isolation: isolate` doesn't help, is there another solution?
[Sample demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cranky-night-m5pp58)

````
$Pin-color: #dc145c;
$White-color: #fff;


.logoContainer {
  top: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  margin-bottom: 29px;
}

.menu {
  top: 128px;
  position: fixed;
}

.navigate ul {
  background: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.chapter {
  background: inherit;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;

  .chapterLink {
    color: $White-color;
    text-decoration: none;

    &:hover {
      color: $Pin-color;
    }
  }
}

.chapter:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}```
````